# MySQL database is saying the password does not meet the required policy yet it should

Tags: mysql

So this is my sql im trying to run (if i can get it to work ill change the password)

```sql
CREATE USER 'foxxything'@'192.168.100.%';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'foxxything'@'192.168.100.%' = '32$jV8klN2nGp2BmLuUb';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `foxxything`.* TO 'foxxything'@'192.168.100.%';
REVOKE REFERENCES, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, INDEX, TRIGGER ON `foxxything`.* FROM 'foxxything'@'192.168.100.%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

here are the password policy's

```
validate_password.dictionary_file   
validate_password.length    8
validate_password.mixed_case_count  1
validate_password.number_count  1
validate_password.policy    MEDIUM
validate_password.special_char_count    1
```

and yet it errors like this.

> Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirementsYour password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

so i dont understand, any help would be a huge help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's throwing that error on the first sql statement when you create the user. Creating the user that way sets the password to nothing which is a violation of the `validate_password` settings.

Instead specify the password when creating the user with the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause:

```
CREATE USER 'foxxything'@'192.168.100.%' IDENTIFIED BY '32$jV8klN2nGp2BmLuUb';
```